# Coroutines, understanding suspend

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-coroutines, coroutine

I'm trying to understand a passage in Hands-On Design Patterns with Kotlin, Chapter 8, Threads and Coroutines.

Why is it that when we rewrite the function as suspend, "we can serve 20 times more users, all thanks to the smart way Kotlin has rewritten our code".

```
fun profile(id:String):Profile {
    val bio = fetchBioOverHttp(id) //takes 1s
    val picture = fetchPictureFromDb(id) // takes 100ms
    val friends = fetchFriendsFromDb(id) // takes 500ms
    return Profile(bio, picture)
}
```

I've attached the two relevant pages but basically, it says "if we have a thread pool of of 10 threads, the first 10 requests will get into the pool and the 11th will get stuck until the first one finishes. This means we can serve three users simultaneously, and the fourth one will wait until the first one gets his/her results."

I think I understand this point. 3 threads execute the three methods in parallel, then another 3, then another 3, which gives us 9 threads actively executing code. The 10th thread executes the first `fetchBioOverHttp` method, and we're out of threads until thread #1 finishes its `fetchBioOverHttp` call.

However, how does rewriting these methods as suspend methods result in serving 20 times more users? I guess I'm not understanding the path of execution here.

[image]
[image]

Comment: The book is really misleading here. The example "with thread" is actually wrong (even when ignoring the poor naming) because it doesn't use future-like return values yet it still pretends that the code takes 1s. We would need parallelism for that, and calling blocking methods returning the unwrapped values wouldn't allow it. Same goes for the "thread pools" example. This is just not how you write async code without coroutines, and this is the main problem I have with the book here. The main advantage of coroutines is the ease with which we can write the async code for similar performance.

Answer (score 4):

To be honest, I don't like this example.

Author meant that after rewriting `httpCall()` it doesn't wait for the result - it schedules processing in the background, registers a callback and then immediately returns. The caller thread is freed and it can start handling another request while the first one is being processed. By using this technique we can process multiple requests while using even a single thread.

I don't like this explanation, because it ignores how coroutines really work internally. Instead, it tries to compare them to something the reader could be familiar with - asynchronous callback-based APIs. Normally, this is good as it helps to understand. However, in this case the problem is that in most cases coroutines internally... create a thread pool and use it to schedule blocking IO operations. Therefore, both provided solutions are pretty much the same and the main difference is that we created a pool of 10 threads and by default coroutines use 64 threads.

Kotlin compiler **does not** cut the function into two. There is still a single function with a lot of additional code inside. I agree it can be interpreted as two functions calling each other, but this is not what the compiler does. If that wasn't explained in the book, I think this is misleading.

Comment: I agree. I haven't read the book, but the extracts given here are taking unacceptable shortcuts IMO.